# Error in installed packages

Tags: package-management, dpkg

what can be done here? as the omsagent has dependency on scx and scx does not like `dpkg --configure -a`.

[image]

Comment: Move `/etc/profile.d/monit.sh` somewhere and try again.

Comment: Read your output: The file `/etc/profile.d/monit.sh` has a syntax error. Fix it.